# Calling a local variable in a class from another class

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance, android-sensors

im having a trouble while i call acce variable of this class

```
public class Slider extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

        public double[] acce={3.00,2.00,1.00};
        public double[] gyro={3.00,2.00,1.00};

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ...
            accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this);
        gyroscope = new Gyroscope(this);

        accelerometer.setListner(new Accelerometer.Listner() {
            @Override
            public double[] onTranslation(float ax, float ay, float az) {
                acce = setAccValue(ax,ay,az);
                return acce;
            }
...
}
```

from this class

```
public void AntremanSayfasi(Context context){
   
    ...
            Slider slider = new Slider();
            AntremanaBasla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aa = (float) slider.acce[0];
                bb = (float) slider.acce[1];
                cc = (float) slider.acce[2];
                accx.setText(String.valueOf(aa));
                accy.setText(String.valueOf(bb));
                accz.setText(String.valueOf(cc));
            }
        });
}
```

the problem is... i can get the determined values but cannot get the updated values of sensor change ?
sorry for rooky question, any help will be appritiated

UPDATE

this is the main Class

```
    public class Slider extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager AktifHareket;
    private LinearLayout mDotLayout;
    private String asd;
    private int asdf;
    private Antreman antreman;
    TextView DenemeSayiCek;
    int position;
    View view;
    int count;
    View viewFix;
    Context context;
//Sensors-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private Accelerometer accelerometer;
    private Gyroscope gyroscope;
    
    public double[] acc={3.00,2.00,1.00};
    public double[] gyr={3.00,2.00,1.00};
    public double[] acce={5.00,5.00,5.00};
    public double[] gyro={3.00,2.00,1.00};
    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Main------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Antreman antreman = new Antreman();
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
        Login login = new Login();
        AktifHareket = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slideViewPager);
        mDotLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);
        SliderAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);
        AktifHareket.setAdapter((sliderAdapter));

        addDotsIndicator();

        //Saydir Buton------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        TextView Deneme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deneme);
        TextView Deneme4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deneme4);
        TextView Deneme3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deneme3);
        TextView Deneme2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deneme2);
        Button Saydir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaydirSlide);
        Button Saydir2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Saydir2Slide);
        Saydir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                position = AktifHareket.getCurrentItem();
                view = AktifHareket.getChildAt(position);
                count = Integer.valueOf(AktifHareket.indexOfChild(view));
                viewFix = AktifHareket.getChildAt(count);
                DenemeSayiCek = (TextView) viewFix.findViewById(R.id.TekrarSayisiSlide);
                asd = (String) DenemeSayiCek.getText().toString();
                asdf = Integer.valueOf(asd);
                asdf++;
                DenemeSayiCek.setText(String.valueOf(asdf));
                Deneme.setText(Arrays.toString(acce));
                Deneme2.setText(String.valueOf(position));
                Deneme3.setText(Arrays.toString(acce));
                Deneme4.setText(String.valueOf(SliderAdapter.POSITION_NONE));

            }
        });

        //Saydir Buton------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //ImageButton-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ImageView logoImage =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        logoImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                antreman.AntremanSayfasi(context);
            }
        });
        antreman.AntremanSayfasi(context);//Açılışta Sayfayı açsın diye
        //ImageButton-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Sensors-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this);
        gyroscope = new Gyroscope(this);

        accelerometer.setListner(new Accelerometer.Listner() {
            @Override
            public double[] onTranslation(float ax, float ay, float az) {
                acce = setAccValue(ax,ay,az);
                Antreman.SensorValues.accValues=acce;
                return acce;
            }

        });

        gyroscope.setListner(new Gyroscope.Listner() {
            @Override
            public void onRotation(float gx, float gy, float gz) {
                setGyroValue(gx,gy,gz);
            }
        });

        //Sensors-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        accelerometer.register();
        gyroscope.register();

    }
    protected void onPouse(){
        super.onPause();

        accelerometer.unregister();
        gyroscope.unregister();

    }

    public double[] setAccValue(double ac, double bc, double cc){
        this.acc[0] = ac;
        this.acc[1] = bc;
        this.acc[2] = cc;
        return acc;
    }

    public double[] setGyroValue(float qq, float wq, float eq){
        this.gyr[0] = qq;
        this.gyr[1] = wq;
        this.gyr[2] = eq;
        return gyr;
    }

    public void getAccValue(double ac, double bc, double cc){
        ac = (float) acce[0];
        bc = (float) acce[1];
        cc = (float) acce[2];

    }
    public void getGyroValue(float qq, float wq, float eq){

        qq = (float) gyro[0];
        wq = (float) gyro[1];
        eq = (float) gyro[2];

    }

    //Sensors---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addDotsIndicator(){

        TextView[] mDots = new TextView[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < mDots.length; i++){
            mDots[i] = new TextView(this);
            mDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            mDots[i].setTextSize(35);
            mDots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

            mDotLayout.addView(mDots[i]);
        }

    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

ant this is the class i need to initialize those values from the main class

```
public class Antreman {
    private Accelerometer accelerometer;
    private Gyroscope gyroscope;
    public double aa;
    public float bb;
    public float cc;
    public float qq;
    public float ww;
    public float ee;

    //Pop up----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void AntremanSayfasi(Context context){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        final View popup_durum = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_durum,null);
        Button AntremanaBasla = popup_durum.findViewById(R.id.basla);
        Button Cikis = popup_durum.findViewById(R.id.cikis);

        dialogBuilder.setView(popup_durum);
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

            TextView gyrox = (TextView) popup_durum.findViewById(R.id.gyrox);

        AntremanaBasla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aa = SensorValues.accValues[0];
                gyrox.setText(String.valueOf(aa));

            }

        });
        Cikis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    static class SensorValues{
        public static double[] accValues = {1.00};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the concept of common class in this case and I believe it will solve your problem quite easily. Follow to steps below.

**Make a public class and declare an array of double inside it which you need to access in another class**

```
  Public class Common{
         public static List<double> acce;
    }
```

and in your activity  where the sensors give updated value use a temp list
and assign it to Common.acce;

```
Common.acce = tempList;
```

Now, when you need to access `acce` just use `Common.acce`, and the reference of tempList is in the Common.acce and when the data in tempList will be updated by your sensor the list in common will be also updated, so ultimately you will get the updated value.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.** And Kindly mark it as the correct answer if it helps you so that in future this answer can help other needy. Happy Coding .

Comment: Hii @Ahmet  If it works for you kindly mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: nope its not the correct ansver. the problem is when i try to reach the value of the array from outside the main class it always gets the declared values, in your scenario it will give me the declared values of {3.00,2.00,1.00}

i want it to give me the values that changed when the sensor changed.

it only gives those values when i call those values from main class and cannot achive to get the right values to another class

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: Rather than assigning values there, You just assign/ update the values where you need. And this method worked for me in many cases. Give it a shot. If doesn't work let me know.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, and yes i tried this and it opened another window on my mind but it cannot achive to get the OnSensorChange values it only brings the declered values not changed ones.... i think its kind of java decleration thing but i need to learn it because it is the log in the pipe.

 by the way thank you...

Comment: ill update the question with full code then you may understand

Comment: yah .. sure do that

Comment: i tried your code in both sides but it didnt give me the solution

Comment: thnx for your time by the way

Comment: if we use list instead of an array would it be a problem for you? Like public static List<Double> acce; and update the values in tempList and assign that tempList to the Common.acce (example : Common.acce  = tempList ). So in this way the reference of tempList is in the Common.acce and when the data in tempList will be updated by your sensor the list in common will be also updated

Comment: nope it will be better i guess, i used array just because its the next step on learning progress Antreman.SensorValues is your Common class by the way

Comment: I just updated the comment above, kindly have a look at it.

Comment: it worked... i must use lists. can you pls write it as an answer i dont want reader lost in comments, it happens to me time to time and its realy annoying

Comment: Did that, and glad to help you